# TDS Package generation failed error

Tags: sitecore-client, tds

I am trying to set up already existing TDS in my local Visual studio. Whenever I build the solution I am getting the below error repeatedly.

> *The package builder failed. Please set the build logging level to Normal or Detailed and see the build output log for more information
> on the failure* this error is getting triggered at the
> HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets (Line 177,5)

For this issue, I have updated the options from minimal to Diagnostic in build & run. And then I tried again to find the root cause from build/team development for the Sitecore output window but there are no errors listed.

Can anyone help me with the above issue?

Comment: I am seeing the same error in TeamCity, whereas I can build using Visual Studio in my local successfully. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your TDS project properties and turn off generate package during build check box

[image]

also turn off  Build web deployment project under Web Deployment Package

[image]

and build the project, this should fix the build issues. once the build is successful, turn on the Generate package during build or Build WebDeploy package or both based on which one you need for your project and rebuild the project.

If you still get the error, try reinstall the TDS for the version of Visual studio you are using and try the steps above.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, The above listed checkboxes are already in turned off state only. Also I have tried reinstalling & installing the TDS again but still same problem exists.

Comment: Hi @Jay, do you have multiple TDS projects in your solution?

Comment: Hi @Mahesh , Yes we have multiple projects , so I followed your steps & unchecked the boxes. Now build is successful. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know it worked, mark my response as accepted answer, so it will be useful for others